# Not working javascript on AJAX in Python

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I hava a HTML program which uses AJAX.THe responseText of the AJAX will be printed on a DIV. Inside that DIV already exist a `<input tpe="text value="" id="fechaD" />`. I have a JQuery function that is called when the input is clicked. Obviously, that input will be replaced by the responseText of the AJAX, so I added again on the responseText. The problem comes that now the JQuery does not work.

I dont know if the `<script type="text/javascript">` with the jQery function should be outside the DIV so it wont be replaced by the response of AJAX, or should be added again as a responseText. I already try both and wont worked.

I have tried this whithout using jQuery and it works, so I think this should have something to do whith my function in jQuery, but my problem is that I didnt programmed that function, because I dont know anything abaout jQuery.

Here is the jQuery Function that works when the input in onclicked:

(The function looks for the ID="fechaD" and displays a Calendar. When the User selects any date, then the date will appear as the input's value. After using AJAX, it wont detect the new ID="fechaD" input).

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($){
            $.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
                monthNames: ['Enero','Febrero','Marzo','Abril','Mayo','Junio','Julio','Agosto','Septiembre','Octubre','Noviembre','Diciembre'],
                dayNamesMin: ['Do','Lu','Ma','Mi','Ju','Vi','S&aacute;'],
            };
            $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['es']);
        });    
        $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#fechaD").datepicker();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: It looks like you have two $(document).ready functions. $(function() { }); is the same thing as $(document).ready. So is jQuery(function($){});

Comment: @DavidJohnson So should I take off the $(document).ready(function()) line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace the `#fechaD` input, the new one will no longer have a `datepicker` instance associated with it.

To solve it, you can either:

1. Call `$('#fechaD').datepicker();` again after replacing it (creates a new datepicker instance);
2. Move the `#fechaD` input outside of the area which you're replacing (recommended).

Comment: I already try to put again the complete JQuery function inside the responseText of the Ajax, so it would be as you said, put again the $(´fechaD').datepicker()'. But it wont work

Comment: @mauguerra Try moving all scripts outside of the element which you're replacing. It'll save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: I have moved them outside the element I am replacing them, but does not detect the new input with the ID="fechaD". This input needs to be inside the responseText, because it would dipslay some values calculated on the AJAX

Comment: And that result calculated server-side must have a datepicker associated with it? Once you append the new data to the page, run `$('#fechaD').datepicker();` in the JS function which appends the data and it'll work. Otherwise edit your question to include some more of your code.

Comment: How do I run ´$('#fechaD').datepicker();´ after appending the new data?

Comment: @mauguerra How are you appending the new data? Must be through some JS XHR or jQuery's `$.ajax`/`$.post`/`$.get`/`.load`. Look for it and add that line after the `.html()` or `.append()` method which will be inside its callback. Post some of your code in the question if you have an idea of where is it or a link.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two $(document).ready functions. $(function() { }); is the same thing as $(document).ready. So is jQuery(function($){});

Maybe try combining them.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">  
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
                    monthNames:   ['Enero','Febrero','Marzo','Abril','Mayo','Junio','Julio','Agosto','Septiembre','Octubre','Noviembre','Diciembre'],
                    dayNamesMin: ['Do','Lu','Ma','Mi','Ju','Vi','S&aacute;'],
                };
                $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['es']);

                $("#fechaD").datepicker();
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: There's absolutely no problem in having more than one DOM ready handler. Combining them is better practice though.

Comment: Do they both get called on load?

Comment: [Exactly](http://jsfiddle.net/nhTBb/). `=]` They are first-in-first-out like all other handlers which are bound as listeners, the only way that one would overwrite another is when you're doing vanilla JS with properties like `element.onclick = function(){}` (as well as the corresponding HTML `onclick=""` which can be overwritten by the `element.onclick` later on).